# MongoDB query for distinct field values that meet a conditional

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named 'sentences'. I would like a list of all the unique values of 'last_syls' where the number of entries containing that value of 'last_syls' is greater than 10.

A document in this collection looks like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "51dd9011cf2bee3a843f215a" ),
  "last_syls" : "EY1D",
  "last_word" : "maid"}
```

I've looked into `db.sentences.distinct('last_syls')`, but cannot figure out how to query based on the count for each of these distinct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/):

```
db.sentences.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$last_syls",
      count: { $sum: 1}
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: { $gt: 10 }
    }
  }
])
```

This groups documents by their `last_syls` field with a count per group, then filters that result set to all results with a `count` greater than 10.